# "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed" when built on 64 bit

Tags: excel, 64-bit, ms-office, ado

I'm using ADO to connect to EXCEL. On my machine office 32 bit is installed. The following code runs fine when built with 32 bit:

```
_ConnectionPtr conn;
conn->Open(connStr, "", "", NULL);
```

Connection string includes:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

When compiled for 64 bit I get: "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed." (hr=-2146824582). Is there a compatibility issue with 64 bit? Should I install 64 bit office? If I do, will my code work when built for 32 bit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Solution: "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable".

Download "AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255 and run “AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe /passive”.

Comment: This link can help you lot in this topic **http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/**

Comment: Just a note. On my 64bit machine, it worked when installed AccessDatabaseEngine.exe, but not AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe. Thanks for the post.