# how to correct the error Could not find installable ISAM VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I reading about this topic but this problem continues, table query is correct, but in the .open step after .ConnectionString the error "Could not find installable ISAM" appears.

**Code in VBA:**

```
With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://sites.com/sites;LIST={endereco_da_tabela_no_SharePoint};"
    .Open
End With
```

libraries have been added: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library

I would like to know how fix this error. Do I need any authorization to access the sharepoint by VBA?
Thank!

Comment: Your listID is correct? See https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/finding-the-id-guid-for-a-sharepoint-list/

Comment: adjust according to the link, thanks!  But when running points another error -> "provider not found. it is possible that it is not installed correctly"

Comment: Hard to tell. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358779/provider-cannot-be-found-it-may-not-be-properly-installed-when-built-on-64-bi